# Get runtime class of a generic type parameter in Kotlin without reified keyword

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin, inline

Kotlin provides a way to get runtime class of a generic type parameter with `reified` keyword which can only be used with `inline` functions. For example the following works:

```
inline fun <reified T> test() : T {
  println(T::class.java)
}
```

However, I need a way of doing this in a *non-inline* function. Since the `reified` keyword is not an option for non-inline functions, the following does not work:

```
fun <reified T> test() : T {
  println(T::class.java)
}
```

Does Kotlin have a different method to solve this problem? I know taking the `Class<T>` as a parameter can be a solution but I don't want to pass an extra argument to my function for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat tricky solution:

```
inline fun <reified T> test() : T = testImpl(T::class.java)
private fun <T> testImpl(`class`: Class<T>) : T {
  println(`class`)
  // do something
}
```

In this solution you're actually passing a `Class` instance but you are not doing it directly. Your invocation code will probably look like `test<Xxx>()`.
If `T` of `test` can be inferred, you can use `test()` directly, and the generic parameter is still passed correctly.

Comment: This solution also needs an inline function which I don't want to use.

Comment: But it's just a forward. I can't think of any other solutions except creating an inlined forward function, considering your condition (no `inline`, no `Class<T>` passed).